# \pause in beamer is changing the theorem counters which is creating issues

Tags: beamer, pause

During a presentation, I asked for a `beamer` template from my friend, and he suggested me to use this. I went ahead with it. I got a suggestion from my supervisor to use `\pause` whenever necessary and while using `\pause` I realised that the theorem counter changes after every `\pause` which is creating issues. How can I modify this code to ensure that the `\pause` does not effect the theorem numbering. Here is the main code from my presentation and at the end of the code, I have used two chapters in `\input{chapter1}` and `\input{chapter2}` where I am writing the main content of the presentation. I tried to refer to other links on TeX.SE but it is not working.

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\makeatletter
\newcounter{theoremcnt}
\ifbeamer@countsect
\newtheorem{theorem}[theoremcnt]{\translate{Theorem}}[section]
\else
\newtheorem{theorem}[theoremcnt]{\translate{Theorem}}
\fi

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}

\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}
\newcounter{corollarycnt}
\newtheorem{corollary}[corollarycnt]{\translate{Corollary}}
\newcounter{factcnt}
\newtheorem{fact}[factcnt]{\translate{Fact}}
\newcounter{lemmacnt}
\newtheorem{lemma}[lemmacnt]{\translate{Lemma}}
\newcounter{problemcnt}
\newtheorem{problem}[problemcnt]{\translate{Problem}}
\newcounter{solutioncnt}
\newtheorem{solution}[solutioncnt]{\translate{Solution}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newcounter{definitioncnt}
\newtheorem{definition}{\translate{Definition}}
\newtheorem{definitions}{\translate{Definitions}}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newcounter{examplecnt}
\newtheorem{example}[examplecnt]{\translate{Example}}
\newtheorem{examples}[examplecnt]{\translate{Examples}}

% Compatibility
\newtheorem{Beispiel}[examplecnt]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{Beispiele}[examplecnt]{Beispiele}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Loesung}[solutioncnt]{L\"osung}
\newtheorem{Satz}[theoremcnt]{Satz}
\newtheorem{Folgerung}[lemmacnt]{Folgerung}
\newtheorem{Fakt}[factcnt]{Fakt}
\newenvironment{Beweis}{\begin{proof}[Beweis.]}{\end{proof}}
\newenvironment{Lemma}{\begin{lemma}}{\end{lemma}}
\newenvironment{Proof}{\begin{proof}}{\end{proof}}
\newenvironment{Theorem}{\begin{theorem}}{\end{theorem}}
\newenvironment{Problem}{\begin{problem}}{\end{problem}}
\newenvironment{Corollary}{\begin{corollary}}{\end{corollary}}
\newenvironment{Example}{\begin{example}}{\end{example}}
\newenvironment{Examples}{\begin{examples}}{\end{examples}}
\newenvironment{Definition}{\begin{definition}}{\end{definition}}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture} % New conjecture environment

\makeatother

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{rose}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \setbeamertemplate{}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\newenvironment<>{proofs}[1][\proofname]{%
    \par
    \def\insertproofname{#1\@addpunct{.}}%
    \usebeamertemplate{proof begin}#2}
{\usebeamertemplate{proof end}}
\makeatother

\title[Annual Progress Seminar]{Cantor's Intersection Theorem}
\author{Rohit K}
\institute{Department of Mathematics, IIT X}
\date{30th September 2023}
\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{iitxlogo.png}}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
% Include your other frames or chapters here
\input{chapter1}
\input{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas, I get that but I cannot do it because as soon as I try to reduce something, it shows errors

Comment: You should replace `\input{chapter1}` and `\input{chapter2}` by some minimal code that shows the problem. Then remove everything, that is not needed for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\resetcounteronoverlays{theoremcnt}` to make sure that overlays don't influence this counter. You will have to do the same for each of your custom counters:

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\makeatletter
\newcounter{theoremcnt}
\ifbeamer@countsect
\newtheorem{theorem}[theoremcnt]{\translate{Theorem}}[section]
\else
\newtheorem{theorem}[theoremcnt]{\translate{Theorem}}
\fi
\resetcounteronoverlays{theoremcnt}


\makeatother

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{rose}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \setbeamertemplate{}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title[Annual Progress Seminar]{Cantor's Intersection Theorem}
\author{Rohit K}
\institute{Department of Mathematics, IIT X}
\date{30th September 2023}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\pause
\begin{theorem}[optional title]
content...
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

... or you could simply use beamer's own theorems instead. They will work with overlays automatically:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\makeatother

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{rose}
    \usefonttheme{serif}
    \setbeamertemplate{}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xfrac}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}

\title[Annual Progress Seminar]{Cantor's Intersection Theorem}
\author{Rohit K}
\institute{Department of Mathematics, IIT X}
\date{30th September 2023}

\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\pause
\begin{theorem}[optional title]
content...
\end{theorem}

\pause

\begin{conjecture}[optional title]
content...
\end{conjecture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. It works. Does beamer have environments defined for conjectures too? I feel it is not, but I can define it manually. Right?

Comment: @zero2infinity You can easily add them, see my edited answer

Comment: will see, thanks